# how to filter the minimums haskell

Tags: list, haskell

now I already have a function that takes the minimum of the list of tuples' first element, for example;

```
mymin [(3,4),(3,2),(4,3)] = 3
```

By using this function, I'd like to take all the tuples which has 3 as its first element. I tried to filter the ones that has 3 on its first element but;

```
filter (\a -> mymin (x:xs) == fst x) (x:xs)
```

which gives

```
[(3,4),(3,2),(4,3)]
```

again because everytime it cuts the list, it finds mymin again, but I just want to take the

```
[(3,4),(3,2)]
```

part, what track should I follow, I stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: `head . groupBy ((==) \`on\` fst) . sortBy (comparing fst)`

Comment: this code is beyond of my haskell experience :p

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use `let` or `where` to precompute the minimum value prior to filtering based on it?

```
yourFilter list = 
  let m = yourMin list
  in filter (\(a, _) -> a == m) list
```

Alternatively, with a point-free style lambda:

```
yourFilter list = 
  let m = yourMin list
  in filter ((== m) . fst) list
```

Comment: yes the scope perform, I totally forgot about that one, suits perfectly thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You only have to replace `x` with `a` in

> filter (\a -> mymin (x:xs) == fst x) (x:xs)

(fst **a** instead of fst **x**)